# Why I unable to disconnect the mongoose mongodb in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


async function run() {
    const connection = await mongoose.connect("mongodb://****:******@127.0.0.1:27017/test_database_1");
    const CatSchema = mongoose.Schema(
        {
            name: String
        }
    )
    const Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', CatSchema, 'Cat')
    const kitty = Cat.create({ name: 'Cat' });
    await connection.disconnect();
}

run()
```

In the above code I tried multiple method like the one stated here [Mongoose Close Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999999/mongoose-close-connection/16000730#16000730) but nothing works i get same error. The code works perfectly if i don't try to disconnect. Below is the error I get

```
MongoNotConnectedError: Client must be connected before running operations
```

Error seem to be little missleading;

Comment: Creation is also asynchronous, but you don't `await` the promise `.create` returns.

Comment: I'd guess that unlike [buffering operations like the `.create()` query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering), buffering `.disconnect()` wouldn't make sense & that's why you're getting an error. Wait until the operation's done before disconnecting (do you need to do that here, at all?)

Comment: Yes, it solves the issue I forgot to await create. Thanks

Comment: @RickN the reason i want to disconnect the in the end of the function because  after running program it doesnot exist, it just keep running even after the operation is done. I don't understand whats the logic behind it. I have to manually ctrl+c to stop the program.