# Mongoose script doesn't terminate properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a node.js script that I want to run periodically that writes to mongodb using mongoose.  It connects to mongodb, writes, and disconnects.  The problem is that the script seems to hang sometimes.  I have to manually terminate the script (ctrl+C).

```
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URL);

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
db.on('open', function() {
    console.log('opened');
});
db.on('close', function() {
    console.log('closed');
});

Model.update(....., function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
});
```

Everything seems to be fine.  The script prints `opened` and `closed` and updates the database correctly, but doesn't terminate after that.  I also disconnect inside the callout after all updates to the database are done so there shouldn't be any pending queries that would prevent the script from terminating.

A similar question was asked here: [Properly close mongoose's connection once you're done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813838/properly-close-mongooses-connection-once-youre-done)
But it doesn't look like there were any true solutions.

EDIT:
I can get it to terminate by adding `process.exit()` at the end, but that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: This exited fine when I tried it, so the problem is likely elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 2):

`mongoose.connection.close()` works for me but you need to make sure all your db operations have completed before calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample script for accessing a Mongo database:

```js
const { Model } = require("../models");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

async function run() {

    let c = `mongodb://${process.env.DBUSER}`;
    c += `:${process.env.DBPASS}`;
    c += `@${process.env.DBHOST}`;
    c += `:${process.env.DBPORT}`;
    c += `/${process.env.DBNAME}`;
    await mongoose.connect(
      c,
      { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
      () => {}
    );
    const db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));

    const instances = await Model.find({});
    for (const i of instances) {
      console.log(i.title);
    }

    mongoose.connection.close();
}


run().catch((error) => console.log(error.stack));
```

If this is saved in a file like script.js, just run `node script.js`.